# How to use @Html.DisplayFor in ForEach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am trying to use `@HTML.DisplayFor` in `@ForEach` statement but not successful.

The following is my existing code:

```
@foreach (var cost in Model.CustomerCost)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@cost .CustomerName</td>
        <td>@(cost.Cost!= 0 ? string.Format("{0:C}", cost.Cost) + " USD" : "-")</td>
    </tr>
}
```

However, i am trying to replace the following line of code

```
<td>@(cost.Cost!= 0 ? string.Format("{0:C}", cost.Cost) + " USD" : "-")</td>
```

with

```
@HTMLDisplayFor

<td>@(cost.Cost!= 0 ? Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerCost[cost].Cost + "USD":"-")</td>
```

What is wrong in @HTML.DisplayFor syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To access the `Cost` property of `cost` use

```
@(cost.Cost != 0 ? Html.DisplayFor(m => cost.Cost) + "USD":"-")
```

Side note: You may want to consider making property `Cost` nullable and using the `DisplayFormat` attribute on the property

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}USD", NullDisplayText = "-")]
public decimal? Cost { get; set; }
```

in which case you can simplify the view to just

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => cost.Cost)
```

Note also the format you were using would be used in a `for` loop where `cost` is the indexer

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.CustomerCost.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CustomerCost[i].Cost)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your explanation. i understand it now. Also thanks for telling handling nullable using data annotation.

Comment: Just added another explanation FYI :)

Comment: Thanks  Stephen Muecke :)

Comment: @Stephan, i used [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", NullDisplayText = "-")] in my model and than <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => cost.Cost)</td>  ------ It shows 0 for nullable but not "-"... Any idea? I think in my case it is not null but 0.0 so NullDisplayText won't work here. Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: The use of `NullDisplayText` is only applicable for a nullable type, so your property would need to be `public decimal? Cost { get; set; }` (or `Nullable<decimal>`) and the value of the property would need to be `null`. I only added that side note because I was a bit puzzled why you would display a zero value as `"-"` rather than `"$0.00USD"`